# Accessing data within an unknown object name

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Let's say I have some JSON:

```
{
    "An unknown value": {
        "some": "values",
        "I": "want",
        "to": "access"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to access the data within an object with an unknown name. This code will run in a Node.js environment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `for .. in` not meet your need?

Comment: [*Object.keys(object)*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.keys) returns an array of the object's own, enumerable property names. Iterate over that.

Comment: @RobG Thanks! I was not aware of this method!

Answer (score 4):

https://jsfiddle.net/ygac8dgg/

```
var object = {
    "An unknown value": {
        "some": "values",
        "I": "want",
        "to": "access"
    },
    "Another":"is",
    "still":"uknown"
};

for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
        console.log("property:",property);
        console.log("value:",object[property]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone's reference, here's **RobG**'s suggestion as a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m4jgyvp0

```
const object = {
   'An unknown value': {
      'some': 'values',
      'I':    'want',
      'to':   'access'
      },
   'Another': 'is',
   'still':   'unknown'
   };

const keys = Object.keys(object);
const array = keys.map(key => ({ key: key, value: object[key] }));
```

[image: keys]

`keys` can be converted to an array of key-value pairs with the `.map()` function, or you could iterate over `keys` with `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading my question again, it is very vague/unclear, and I can't seem to remember the context of this.

However in other situations, where I need to access an object via a dynamic key, one can use:

```
const key: string = "aKeyFromSomeWhere"
const value = object[key]
```

rather than
`object.aKnownKey`